# RavenDb Different Database Instance Include

Tags: data-modeling, ravendb

Is there a way to include a document from other RavenDb database instance to be loaded in our current store session?

> The question is based from not being able to have categorized
> collections in RavenDb studio, so it's annoying to scroll and find a
> desired collection!
>
> In another word, having bounded-context in a same document store is
> not looking good, so the best solution is to split the stores to make
> it more efficient and readable as well.

*I know that this is not a best practice to store different bounded-context in a very same db instance, but what if I need that!*

**Update**:

> **Seems like Cross-Database functions are not available in RavenDb.**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass info/documents between 2 different RavenDB databases then you can always use the **[External Replication Task](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/studio/database/tasks/ongoing-tasks/external-replication-task)** or the **[RavenDB ETL task](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/studio/database/tasks/ongoing-tasks/ravendb-etl-task)**.

RavenDB ETL Task:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/studio/database/tasks/ongoing-tasks/ravendb-etl-task

External Replication Task:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/studio/database/tasks/ongoing-tasks/external-replication-task

With the **ETL task option**, you can use a script to define and/or filter what is sent to the other RavenDB Database. Once a document reaches the target database you can use/load/include as usual.

Comment: This is true, but it will make a mess in the first db with many collections from the second.
It's not worth it. 
Using ETL, is the recommended technique in microservice architecture and this is not what I'm asking about. Pollution made by collections in RavenDb Studio is an issue. If there was a way to create folders and attach collections to those, it may solve the pollution and including matter as well. Therefor, creating another Database will not be needed anymore.